# how to select update in the same table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `emp(eid, ename, sal, mgr)`. Now I want to update the manager salary whose salary is less than 50000/-.

```
UPDATE emp AS t1 INNER JOIN
(SELECT mgr FROM emp WHERE mgr = t1.empno) AS t2
SET sal = sal + 5000
WHERE t1.sal <50000;
```

what should I do?

Comment: `update emp set sal = {what ever you want} where sal < 50000`

Comment: `update emp set sal=newamount where sal <50000`

Comment: Please post your query as well.

Comment: I want to update only mgrs salary not all employees!!!

Comment: Sure, but provide some sample data and query you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use subquery, to update data that depends on same table i.e:

```
UPDATE sometable set field = null 
WHERE sometable.id in (SELECT * FROM (SELECT id from sometable) as a);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to update the manager salary whose salary is less than 50000/

why you need a `SELECT` BTW. Just perform `UPDATE` operation like

```
update emp
set sal = 70000
where sal < 50000;
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, I much prefer using `JOIN` for this type of update to using the doubly nested `IN` expression.  The `JOIN` allows the optimizer to make use of available indexes:

```
UPDATE emp mgr INNER JOIN
       emp e
       ON e.empno = mgr.mgr
    SET mgr.sal = mgr.sal + 5000
    WHERE mgr.sal < 50000;
```